# Synthesizing the interface of T required by a class template

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>  
class A  
{  
    // use the type parameter T in various ways here  
}
```

Is there any way to automatically synthesize a workable class definition for T, as used by the template A? My expectation is a tool or a compiler trick that could generate the boiler plate code for the type parameter T, which I could tweak further to my needs.

I know if I wrote the class A, I could provide some hints to the "user" using boost concepts checks etc... But it's an unfamiliar code base where I didn't have the luxury of writing class A. So far I build the needed parameter class T manually, by reading the code for class A and with the able assistance from the compiler (with its terse messages).

Is there a better way?

Comment: From the wording of your question, I'm kinda expecting the answer, but... what about the documentation?

Comment: You should first of all think about what `A` needs and publish a set of requirements, and then program `A` to rely solely on those requirements. You can then think separately about making a scaffold for a class that conforms to those requirements.

Comment: @KerrekSB As I said, I don't have the luxury of writing the class A. Infact there are many such classes that have been written already.

Comment: @Xeo Yes existing documentation (however poor) covers the "core" requirements for T, but there's always a missing operator here, one esoteric function there and so on which are caught only at compile time and need to be fixed iteratively.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to automatically generate a [concept archetype](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/concept_check/concept_covering.htm) for a given template class. Currently, this is not possible and maybe it never will be.

The main problem here is that it is very hard to say anything about the semantics of `A`s code without any a priori knowledge of `T`. Dave Abrahams wrote a [blog post](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/12/a-breakthrough-for-concepts/) not too long ago, where he showed that it is possible to to call an unconstrained function from code that is constrained by concepts and the compiler will still be able to perform the concept checks correctly.

But what you are asking for is a compiler that synthesizes concept checks out of thin air. I'm not much of a compiler person but I can't think of a way to make this possible with today's tools. Although it surely would be very cool if this became possible some day.

Comment: Well, one possibility would be to just iterate over the methods and check how each variable of type `T` is used. However, you get back to the halting problem with things like `another_template<T> foo; foo.do_something();` used inside such a method. The checking could possibly be endless.

Comment: Why would checking be endless? After all the compiler can deduce all the errors. Not sure how this is the same as halting problem.

Comment: Consider a basic example of template metaprogramming: iterating a typelist. You instantiate the same `iterate<List>` template over and over until you have processed the entire list and end up with a specialization for `iterate<Empty_List>`. Since TMP is turing-complete, the general case will always be the halting problem.

Comment: Honestly I am still not convinced though you may be right. Intuitively iterating over a recursive template is different from the generating the required interface. You might as well say that compiling c++ is a halting problem because TMP is turing complete.

Comment: Compiling is a halting problem in the same sense as executing a program on a Turing Machine is one: As long as the program runs you have no means of knowing whether it might actually terminate one day or will go on forever. Some of the earliest examples of TMP programs would never complete compilation but would output results through compiler error messages.

Comment: Exactly my point! despite it being a halting problem there are compilers. Why can't there be a tool to do what I need? That's the part I am not sure about ... :)

Comment: The halting problem does not forbid to solve special cases, i.e. you can write a solver that decides for *some* programs whether they halt. You just cannot solve the general case, i.e. for any such solver you can construct a program where the solver does not work. It's the same here: We may be able to solve some special cases and maybe that's enough. Still, synthesizing types is a lot harder than compiling, so I'm quite sure there remains a set of compilable programs for which this problem is not solvable.